# GlassFish Server jdbc can't insert records into the database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I have configured my GlassFish Server over the administration console and added the JDBC Connection Pools and JDBC Resources. Pinging over the administration console from GlassFish works with succes. I am creating the Database object and calling the inserting method from the Database class.

```
Database database = new Database();
BigInteger acSerial = att.getSerialNumber();
BigInteger pkcSerial = att.getHolder().getSerialNumber();
String AC = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(att.getEncoded());
database.inserting(acSerial,pkcSerial,AC);
```

Here is my inserting method from the Database class:

```
public class Database {
        // JDBC driver name and database URL
        static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AC?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

        //  Database credentials
        static final String USER = "XXXXXX";
        static final String PASS = "XXXXXXXX";

        public void inserting(BigInteger acparam, BigInteger pkcparam, String encoded) {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try{
                //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                //STEP 3: Open a connection
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                //STEP 4: Execute a query
                stmt = conn.createStatement();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO ACCredentials " + "VALUES (" +acparam +"," +pkcparam +"," +"'"+encoded+"'" +")" + "";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }catch(SQLException se){
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                //finally block used to close resources
                try{
                    if(stmt!=null)
                        conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se){
                }
                try{
                    if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is nothing is inserted into the MySQL database. I have tried this insert example without GlassFish Server and it worked. Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: looking into your issue, but an off topic comment- hard coding credentials is a very bad idea. Try creating a JNDI resource and draw them from the server (easier than jdbc resources to be honest)

Comment: i deleted the last comment, what i should have commented is- ACCredntials has 3 columns correct?

Comment: that's true, ACCredentials has 3 columns.

Comment: I am honestly seeing no issue...

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions: don't do that, at minimum log them.

Comment: @Mark on the server I don't see the output of System.out.println. How do you print then the error or it is better to logg the exceptions? Can you give an example.

Comment: Use a logging framework, or use `exception.printStackTrace()` so it's written to the error stream, which is usually (but not always) written to the application server logs.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem. I forgot the DataSource part:

```
 public void inserting(BigInteger acparam, BigInteger pkcparam, String encoded) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ctx;
        DataSource ds;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MeinDatasourceJndiName");
            //ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MySQLDataSource");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO ACCredentials " + "VALUES (" +acparam +"," +pkcparam +"," +"'"+encoded+"'" +")" + "";
            //rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


            while(rs.next()) {
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {

        }
```